# Update the existing data to the table

Tags: java, jsp

I want to update the existing record but its creating  new record.

In the user interface in the following picture I click the submit button and it should update the data which its already in database.

[image]

This does not work since a new entry is created.

```
public void onSave()
    {
        carRepository.save(car);

// (idea:on save  if the data exists update the one or create new one)
}
```

Comment: Without looking at the code, noone would be able to help you. Also you could try debugging your code and try finding the mistake yourself.

Comment: What are you using to persist the data? Hibernate?

Comment: storing data in Oracle SQl
Hibernate

Comment: Post your code here, thats how we can help you, otherwise, its just like blind watching elephant. And another question , the carRepository instance of what?